# Should I specify who is doing the action when I use "it" as dummy subject?

Tags: infinitives, subjects

Should I specify who is doing the action when I use "it" as dummy subject? For instance:

> **It would be interesting to tell us about ...**

Is this okay?

Comment: you can use 'would' when we imagine an **action** or **situation**, so it sounds correct.

Comment: No no. I know that. Maybe my question was a bit unclear. I meant that I want someone (for instance you) to tell me something and I say this sentence "It would be interesting to tell us about..." Will the people understand what I mean?

Comment: Ah yes, sounds good to me. You can start with so, then, It would be ...., this might help more with your intention.

Answer (score 1):

While the statement seems correct grammatically, it sounds like something is missing.

Even if there are prior statements clarifying who is doing the action (to tell), a subject is still welcome:

> It would be interesting **if you / they** tell us about ...

Pairing properly the verbs ("would be" vs. "tell"), the sentence becomes:

> It would be interesting **if you / they** ***told*** us about ...

Comment: I agree, but I would prefer “told” to “tell” here following the “would”.